# Parsing outlook .msg files with python to get HTML body

Tags: python, email, outlook, python-3.6

I looked around on StackOverflow and couldn't find a satisfactory answer for getting an HTML body from the `msg` file. Does anyone know how to parse .msg files from outlook with Python?

I've tried using `extract_msg` and `msg_parser` with no luck. Help would be greatly appreciated!

I have also used `chardet.detect` to detect the encoding but sometimes it misbehave with some bullets point likes `.` to `Ã‚Â·`

Example Code :

```
msg = extract_msg.openMsg('test.msg')
msg_obj = MsOxMessage('test.msg')

html = ''
try:
    body_encoding = chardet.detect(msg.htmlBody)['encoding']
    html = msg.htmlBody.decode(body_encoding) if msg.htmlBody else ''
except:
    html = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that MSG files created by Outlook do not contain the `PR_HTML` MAPI property (unlike the messages in an Outlook store that natively supports HTML); the HTML is encoded inside the `PR_RTF_COMPRESSED` property, which contains compressed RTF stream - take a look an an MSG file with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click "More functions | OpenIMsgOnIStg".

You can use Outlook Object Model to call [Namespace.OpenSharedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.openshareditem) and then read  [MailItem.HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property, but Outlook Object Model cannot be used in a service (such as IIS) and a temporary message will be created in the default store, which means Outlook needs to log to a profile first.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author - it is an Extended MAPI wrapper and it can be used from a service in any language), you can use [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetMessageFromMsgFile` and then read [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`HTMLBody` property.